# Okhttp4, Cannot access 'body': it is package-private in 'Response'

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp

i'm migrating from okhttp 3.14 to okhttp4, accordings to migration guide, when replacing **"response.body()?"** call to **"response.body?"** IDE shows error " *Cannot access 'body': it is package-private in 'Response'* " at last line of code

```
val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
        val response = coreNetwork.getOkHttp().newCall(request).execute()
        val stream = response.body?.source()?.inputStream()
```

if i'm trying **"response.body()?"** call, shows error " *Using 'body(): ResponseBody?' is an error. moved to val* " as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved, i'm start watching to what version of okhttp linked every import, and one interface linked to *okhttp-3.12.0.jar*. This interface belongs to separate gradle module, and i found that i forgot add a dependency ' *implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.2.2"* ' to .gradle file of that module. (in that case class should not found okhttp dependency at all, but somehow found old version and depends on it)

Answer (score 0):

This is an expected error message looking at the code for `Response.kt` in the 4.2.x version of the branch:

```
@JvmName("-deprecated_body")
@Deprecated(
    message = "moved to val",
    replaceWith = ReplaceWith(expression = "body"),
    level = DeprecationLevel.ERROR)
fun body(): ResponseBody? = body
```

so the solution would be to call `response.body?` which it looks like you are already doing...

see: https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/okhttp_4.2.x/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/Response.kt#L202 for details